# Save web page in local hard disk using Jquery or js click on imge button (like Ctrl-s event)

Tags: jquery, save

I have a image button named "save page" . I want add functionality to save web page in local hard disk same like as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> event do. Is It possible using jquery or js?

Answer (score 3):

HTML and Javascript do not have any access to File System for security consideration.
If they have this ability, then it will be easy to spread computer virus.